# Can't get / delete / update Facebook posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB's graph API.

I kept running into this useless error message for an hour, until I tested giving myself extra permissions which got it to actually work for a get request.

```
{ error:
   { message: 'Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api',
     type: 'GraphMethodException',
     code: 100 } }
```

Now, at least using the Graph Explorer, I can GET using the POST_ID as per their documentation.

However, when I POST to that id, I receive an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid post id", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

And when I run a DELETE request to that ID, I receive:

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

However, the post never actually is deleted.

I tried to report this bug to Facebook, but even the bug reporting kept crashing and I couldn't get the bug through.

I want to create a feature where I post to a bunch of different groups to verify that I have permission, then delete the post immediately after.

At this pace, I will never in my lifetime make it happen. Does anyone have any insights into why I am receiving this litany of errors, and how to actually successfully DELETE these posts?

Let alone the fact that now I am discovering I need extra permissions I have to go through another app-vetting by Facebook, I am quickly thinking that throwing away my plans for this feature is probably my best bet.

Comment: What API request are you making to get the post id? What is the id returned?

Comment: I actually have further news to report on this issue and was able to get it working eventually. I'll post the news here in a couple hours.